# VT-Direct Integration (Mandiri Bill Payment) Expired in 24 hours

Tags: php, node.js, payment-gateway, loopback

Using **VT-Direct Integration (Mandiri Bill Payment)** for a web app in Indo, the problem i am facing is transaction get expired after 24 hours, if customer fails to pay the money with  **Mandiri Bill Payment**, i want to change this to 48 hours, any one with Veritans ? response appreciated.

here is the api url :

https://docs.midtrans.com/en/vtdirect/integration_mbill.html

```
transaction = {
    payment_type: 'echannel',
    transaction_details: {
        order_id: id_order,
        gross_amount: total_paid
    },
    item_details: txn_products,
    echannel: {
        bill_info1: "Payment For: " + id_order,
        bill_info2: "debt"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 transaction = {
                payment_type: 'echannel',
                transaction_details: {
                    order_id: id_order,
                    gross_amount: total_paid
                },
                item_details: txn_products,
                echannel: {
                    bill_info1: "Payment For: " + id_order,
                    bill_info2: "debt"
                },
                custom_expiry: {
                    expiry_duration: 2,
                    unit: 'day'
                }
            };
```

add custom_expiry and you are good !